# mysqldump extreme export slowness

Tags: mysql-5.7, linux, mysqldump

I'm using MySql 5.7.33 on VmWare Vsphere Vm with 20GB RAM and 8 cores.
These are my MySql settins

```
slow_query_log      = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 13G 
innodb_log_file_size = 1200M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2 
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_io_capacity = 10000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 20000
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=13
query_cache_limit       = 32M
query_cache_size        = 0
query_cache_type        = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_lru_scan_depth=256
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode =2
sync_binlog=0 
bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
join_buffer_size = 2M 
sort_buffer_size = 512K
table_open_cache=4000
innodb_open_files=4000
max_connections=300
```

As many DBA does nightly I made a dump of all dbs and for last 2 years I haven't any problems. This server hosts 3 db, 2 are little and the main db is more or less 45GB which means 18 GB sql dump using this command

```
mysqldump --login-path=<my cred set> --add-drop-table --extended-insert --no-tablespaces <my dbname> > <my dump file>
```

Recently this operation become insanely slow. Normally it takes a little more than one hour but every night it becames slower so it takes 2 hours, 4 hours... then I must kill the process because it saturates all 300 connections and noone can connect to mysql!

After killing the dump process all the things runs as normal and during the day I didn't notice any problems or slowness.

If a force a stop/start of mysql service the problem disapper! the nightly dump takes little more than one hour and all the thins runs as expected.

I've tried to monitoring queries activities to prevent any abnormal situations that could justify what happened but I didn't found anything!
The queries are more ore less the same and I didn't notice any abnormal process that could cause the problem.

I take a look at i/o wa but it seems that is all ok.

After few days from mysql service restart mysqldump become progressively slow and the nightly dump takes more than expected. Meanwhile queries are queued and all available connections (300) are used so mysql start to reply with "too many connection" until I kill mysqldump process.

in mysql error.log I found

```
[Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 6825ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=15 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

but it depends from mysqldump slowness because normally I didn't notice that warning.

I've tried mysqltuner.pl which said:

```
General recommendations:
    Check error line(s) in /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    max_connections (> 300)
    wait_timeout (< 28800)
    interactive_timeout (< 28800)
    skip-name-resolve=1
    join_buffer_size (> 2.0M, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    key_buffer_size (~ 277M)
    key_buffer_size (> 3.5G)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 41.6G) if possible.
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=1G) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals 25% of buffer pool size.
```

It seems is time to brings more RAM but I'm not sure mysqltuner.pl is giving the right advice. I mean, adding more RAM could only improve general performance, but I would to be sure that this help to solve my problem.

Obviously I cannot restart MySQL periodically.. which are the metrics to look at to troubleshoot the problem?
Could I find usefull infos in mysql status variables?

Comment: What else is running in the VM, apart from MySQL? What else is running on the _hardware_ hosting this VM? Do you over-commit CPU resources, by chance? Any interesting messages in the syslog during these "slow dump" times?

Comment: @mustaccio : apart mysql few cli php scripts (mem peak usage 300MB). CPU resources are not over-commit. Haven't found any interesting syslog messages. I guess I'll try to add more RAM, at the moment it seems the only reasonable solution.